# glGetQueryObjectuiv, "Bound query buffer is not large enough to store result."

Tags: performance, opengl, opengl-4, occlusion

I am trying to solve an error I get when I run [this sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/gl_440/Gl_440_query_occlusion.java).

It regards query occlusion, essentially it renders four times a square changing everytime viewport but only the central two times it will actually render something since the first and the last viewport are outside the monitor area on purpose.

```
    viewports[0] = new Vec4(windowSize.x * -0.5f, windowSize.y * -0.5f, windowSize.x * 0.5f, windowSize.y * 0.5f);
    viewports[1] = new Vec4(0, 0, windowSize.x * 0.5f, windowSize.y * 0.5f);
    viewports[2] = new Vec4(windowSize.x * 0.5f, windowSize.y * 0.5f, windowSize.x * 0.5f, windowSize.y * 0.5f);
    viewports[3] = new Vec4(windowSize.x * 1.0f, windowSize.y * 1.0f, windowSize.x * 0.5f, windowSize.y * 0.5f);
```

Each of this time, it will `glBeginQuery` with a different query and render a first time and then I query `GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED`

```
    // Samples count query
    for (int i = 0; i < viewports.length; ++i) {

        gl4.glViewportArrayv(0, 1, viewports[i].toFA_(), 0);

        gl4.glBeginQuery(GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, queryName.get(i));
        {
            gl4.glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount, 1);
        }
        gl4.glEndQuery(GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED);
    }
```

Then I try to read the result

```
    gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.QUERY));
    IntBuffer params = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewports.length; ++i) {
        params.put(0, i);
        gl4.glGetQueryObjectuiv(queryName.get(i), GL_QUERY_RESULT, params);
    }
```

But I get:

```
GlDebugOutput.messageSent(): GLDebugEvent[ id 0x502
    type Error
    severity High: dangerous undefined behavior
    source GL API
    msg GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Bound query buffer is not large enough to store result.
    when 1455696348371
    source 4.5 (Core profile, arb, debug, compat[ES2, ES3, ES31, ES32], FBO, hardware) - 4.5.0 NVIDIA 356.39 - hash 0x238337ea]
```

If I look on the [api doc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetQueryObject.xhtml) they say:

```
params

    If a buffer is bound to the GL_QUERY_RESULT_BUFFER target, then params is treated as an offset to a location within that buffer's data store to receive the result of the query. If no buffer is bound to GL_QUERY_RESULT_BUFFER, then params is treated as an address in client memory of a variable to receive the resulting data.
```

I guess there is an error in that phrase, I think they meant `GL_QUERY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_QUERY_RESULT_BUFFER`, indeed they use `GL_QUERY_BUFFER` also [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/query_buffer_object.txt) for example..
Anyway, if anything is bound there, then params is interpreted as offset, ok

but my buffer is big enough:

```
    gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.QUERY));
    gl4.glBufferData(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, Integer.BYTES * queryName.capacity(), null, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, 0);
```

So what's the problem?

I tried to write a big number, such as 500, for the buffer size, but no success...

I guess the error lies somewhere else.. could you see it?

Comment: "*my buffer is big enough:*" I don't see how that shows that the buffer is big enough. What does `queryName.capacity` return? Equally importantly, what does it mean to pass `params` to `glGetQueryObject`? Does that mean passing a client pointer, or does that mean passing an integer offset?

Comment: Both `queryName.capacity()` and `Integer.BYTES` return 4, so that's 16 bytes in total. About `params`, I assume it expects an integer offset (since the binding of `GL_QUERY_BUFFER`).. on the `C#` equivalent code `BUFFER_UINT_OFFSET(i)` is used instead, where `#define BUFFER_UINT_OFFSET(i) ((GLuint *)NULL + (i))`.

Comment: I'm know what OpenGL expects that parameter to mean. I'm asking you what passing `params` to that function actually does. I don't know anything about C# interfaces to OpenGL (and you never mentioned the language). But it looks like to me that if you pass a `*Buffer` type to one of the OpenGL functions that take a pointer, it is interpreted to mean that you're passing a *client array*, not an integer offset.

Comment: I guess I lost you, I am not really sure what you mean by _client array_.. anyway, if I have to answer, I say I expect that if I bind a buffer to `GL_QUERY_BUFFER` target, then OpenGL should read the value inside `params` and interpreter that as the offset (in bytes) where it should save the result of the query to. Anyway, if I don't bind any buffer, I retrieve the expected result in `params`, I don't know if this is what you meant by _client array_..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I have to answer, I say I expect that if I bind a buffer to GL_QUERY_BUFFER target, then OpenGL should read the value inside params and interpreter that as the offset (in bytes) where it should save the result of the query to.

No, that's not how it works.

In C/C++, the value taken by `glGetQueryObject` is a pointer, which *normally* is a pointer to a client memory buffer. For this particular function, this would often be a stack variable:

```
GLuint val;
glGetQueryObjectuiv(obj, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &val);
```

`val` is declared by client code (ie: the code calling into OpenGL). This code passes a pointer to that variable, and `glGetQueryObjectuiv` will write data to this pointer.

This is emulated in C# bindings by using `*Buffer` types. These represent contiguous arrays of values from which C# can extract a pointer that is compatible with C and C++ pointers-to-arrays.

However, when a buffer is bound to `GL_QUERY_BUFFER`, the meaning of the parameter changes. As you noted, it goes from being a client pointer to memory into an offset. But please note what that says. It does *not* say a "client pointer *to an offset*".

That is, the *pointer value itself* ceases being a pointer to actual memory. Instead, the numerical value of the pointer is treated as an offset.

In C++ terms, that's this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, buff);
glGetQueryObjectuiv(obj, GL_QUERY_RESULT, reinterpret_cast<void*>(16));
```

Note how it takes the offset of 16 bytes and pretends that this value is actually a `void*` who's numerical value is 16. That's what the reinterpret cast does.

How do you do that in C#? I have no idea; it would depend on the binding you're using, and you never specified what that was. Tao's long-since dead, and [OpenTK looks to be heading that way too](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/commit/2e51fe019771f4c70b15bb25b3a560f712a45fbf). But I did [find out how to do this in OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/opengl/geometry/attributes).

What you need to do is this:

```
gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_QUERY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.QUERY));
for (int i = 0; i < viewports.length; ++i)
{
    gl4.glGetQueryObjectuiv(queryName.get(i), GL_QUERY_RESULT,
        (IntPtr)(i * Integer.BYTES));
}
```

You multiply times `Integer.BYTES` because the value is a *byte offset* into the buffer, not the integer index into an array of ints.

Comment: Sorry Nicol, I gave it for granted, my bad, but actually my code is a jogl port of a C# sample. It is a problem about how jogl calls the native function in then.. your answer has really been insightful, thank you